# How to change Django static files

Tags: javascript, django, static-files

I know this might be a really obvious question, but I'm doing a Django project where I have Javascript in my static files. However, I have noticed that whenever I make a change to those files, my web server doesn't reflect the changes. Is there some migration or something else I need to do to make my web server reflect changes to my static Javascript files? Thanks.

Comment: It could be that all you need is refresh while holding shift. Sounds like the browser is simply caching the files.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks! Your suggestion worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to run `python manage.py collectstatic` on the webserver to put the static files in the correct folder. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Another possible issue is caching. You could use ManifestStaticFilesStorage https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage to have new filenames whenever a file is updated and escape cache issues.